# Auxiliary randomization and the generalized CDF inverse

Tags: probability, self-study, simulation, quantiles, cumulative-distribution-function

I'm trying to solve Homework 4 from professor Ryan Tibshirani's class on "Advanced Topics in Statistical Learning" [[pdf](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Eryantibs/statlearn-s23/homeworks/homework4.pdf)] at UC Berkeley. It deals with basic facts about CDFs and quantiles.

My question is regarding Exercise 1(f) where the author mentions an **auxiliary randomization** method which extends the well known result of random variable generation via the inverse CDF to cases where it might fail (I suppose non-continuous pdfs?)

I'll rewrite the method here below: Let $X$ be distributed according to $F$. Define,
$$
F^\star(x; v) = \lim_{y \to x^{-}} F(y) + v \cdot \Big(F(x) - \lim_{y \to x^{-}} F(y)\Big)
$$
where $y \to x^-$ means that $y$ approaches $x$ from the left.

It is possible to show that for $V \sim U(0, 1)$, independent of $X$, and for any $t$, we have
$$
\mathbb{P}(F^\star(X; V) \leq t) = t
$$

**Question**: Does anyone know of a reference (article? standard book?) where I can read more about this result? I admit that I'm having some trouble to understand the intuition and motivation for creating the auxiliary variable $v$ here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The statement "*$y \to x^+$ means that $y$ approaches $x$ from the left*" is unconventional -- most of the time it means $y$ approaches $x$ from the **right**.

Comment: Thanks @Zhanxiong! I've corrected the statement. It seems to be a typo in the original homework that I cited in my question.

Comment: You should correct $x^+$ to $x^-$ instead of correcting "left" to "right", as your linked pdf document does.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented under you post, I will use "$f(x-)$" instead of "$f(x+)$" for the left limit of a function $f$ in the proof below.

##### Preparations

The key of the proof is a property of the *quantile function* of a random variable $X$. In general, if $X$ is a random variable with distribution function $F$, we can define its quantile function (see, e.g., Equation (14.5) in *Probability and Measure* by Patrick Billingsley) of $X$ as
\begin{align}
\varphi(u) = \inf[x: F(x) \geq u], \quad 0 < u < 1. 
\end{align}
For fixed $u \in (0, 1)$, we will need the following property of $\varphi$ (the proof of it can also be found in the reference mentioned above):
\begin{align}
& x \geq \varphi(u) \iff F(x) \geq u, \tag{1} \\
& x < \varphi(u) \iff F(x) < u. \tag{2}
\end{align}

As a rigorous proof, some properties of measure-theoretic integral will also be used tacitly. If you have questions, please comment below the answer.

##### Proof

Denote $F^\star(X; V) = F(X-) + V(F(X) - F(X-))$ by $U$, to show $U \sim U(0, 1)$, it suffices to show for any $u \in (0, 1)$, it holds that $P[U < u] = u$.

To this end, let's denote the set of discontinuities of $F$ by $J$, it then follows by the independence between $X$ and $V$ and $(2)$ that
\begin{align}
 & P[U < u] = P[U < u, X \in J] + P[U < u, X \in J^c] \\
=& P[F(X-) + V(F(X) - F(X-)) < u, X \in J] + P[F(X) < u, X \in J^c] \\
=& \int_J P\left[V < \frac{u - F(x-)}{F(x) - F(x-)}\right]dF(x) + 
P[X < \varphi(u), X \in J^c] \\
=& \int_J P\left[V < \frac{u - F(x-)}{F(x) - F(x-)}\right]dF(x) + 
\int_{J^c \cap (-\infty, \varphi(u))} dF(x). \tag{3}
\end{align}

Let's analyze the integrand of the first term in the right-hand of $(3)$: If $x \in (-\infty, \varphi(u)) \cap J$, then $F(x-) < F(x) < u$ by the monotonicity of $F$ and $(2)$, whence $\frac{u - F(x-)}{F(x) - F(x-)} > 1$ and it then follows by $V \sim U(0, 1)$ that $P\left[V < \frac{u - F(x-)}{F(x) - F(x-)}\right] = 1$; if $x \in (\varphi(u), +\infty) \cap J$, then for every $t \in (\varphi(u), x)$, by $(1)$ we have $F(t) \geq F(\varphi(u)) \geq u$, hence $F(x-) = \lim_{t \to x^-}F(t) \geq u$, whence $\frac{u - F(x-)}{F(x) - F(x-)} \leq 0$ and it then follows by $V \sim U(0, 1)$ that $P\left[V < \frac{u - F(x-)}{F(x) - F(x-)}\right] = 0$. This implies that (decompose $J$ into $J = [J \cap (-\infty, \varphi(u))] \cup [J \cap \{\varphi(u)\}] \cup [J \cap (\varphi(u), +\infty)]$):
\begin{align}
 & \int_J P\left[V < \frac{u - F(x-)}{F(x) - F(x-)}\right]dF(x) \\
=& \int_{J \cap (-\infty, \varphi(u))} dF(x) + \int_{J \cap \{\varphi(u)\}}
P\left[V < \frac{u - F(x-)}{F(x) - F(x-)}\right]dF(x). \tag{4}
\end{align}

$(3)$ and $(4)$ together then give
\begin{align}
P[U < u] = \int_{(-\infty, \varphi(u))} dF(x) + \int_{J \cap \{\varphi(u)\}}
P\left[V < \frac{u - F(x-)}{F(x) - F(x-)}\right]dF(x). \tag{5}
\end{align}

To simplify $(5)$, consider the following two cases:

Case 1: $\varphi(u) \in J^c$, i.e., $F$ is continuous at $\varphi(u)$.  In this case the second term in the right-hand side of $(5)$ vanishes, and $F(\varphi(u)) = F(\varphi(u)-)$. $(5)$ thus reduces to
\begin{align}
P[U < u] = \int_{(-\infty, \varphi(u))} dF(x) = P[X < \varphi(u)] = 
F(\varphi(u)-) = F(\varphi(u)) = u. 
\end{align}

Case 2: $\varphi(u) \in J$, i.e., $F$ jumps at $\varphi(u)$.  In this case the second term in the right-hand side of $(5)$ becomes
\begin{align}
& \int_{\{\varphi(u)\}}P\left[V < \frac{u - F(x-)}{F(x) - F(x-)}\right]dF(x) \\
=& P\left[V < \frac{u - F(\varphi(u)-)}{F(\varphi(u)) -F(\varphi(u)-)}\right] \times (F(\varphi(u)) -F(\varphi(u)-)) \\
=& u - F(\varphi(u)-).
\end{align}
Therefore $(5)$ reduces to
\begin{align}
P[U < u] = P[X < \varphi(u)] + u - F(\varphi(u)-) = 
F(\varphi(u)-) + u - F(\varphi(u)-) = u.
\end{align}

This completes the proof.

Comment: Thanks! I'm having trouble to see how you arrive at Equation (4). While I do understand the paragraph that precedes the equation, I don't see how you end up with that first integral on the RHS of (4). Also, is it correct to say that you split the space of X into three parts (x < phi(u), x = phi(u), and x > phi(u)) and that the integral on x > phi(u) is always zero? Finally, do we always have that F(x-) = F(x)? or is this something specially from the properties of the problem?

Comment: @PedroRodrigues For the first two questions, I elaborated the paragraph preceding Eq (4).  For the last question, of course we do NOT always have $F(x-) = F(x)$ ($F(x) > F(x-)$ corresponds to the case $x \in J$ in the answer) -- this is actually the full point of this exercise, i.e., how to simulate random numbers from an $F$ that may have jump points.  To gain a good understanding of it, I suggested you completing every sub-question in that pdf sequentially before jumping into this last bonus one.